# Variable syntax error (Python)

Tags: python, syntax

I'm new to coding with python and I've came across an issue with my variables in an "if" or "else" command.

```
Answer = input("Yo stupid, What\'s nine plus ten?")
if Answer == 19: print("Your smarter then me.")
else Answer >= 21: print("You stupid!")
```

^^
When I attempt to run my code It tells me I have made an error with my syntax. It always pops up with my variable "Answer" in the "if" or "else" command. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `elif` instead of `else`

Comment: Additionally, `input` returns a string, so `"19" == 19` will be false.

Answer (score 4):

`elif` (short for "else if") should be used if you want to test another condition for `Answer`. `else` is used on its on for every other option that `Answer` could be that doesn't fit the previous conditionals.

Comment: Should also mention that the conditionals are resulting in a `TypeError`, it should be `if Answer == '19'`, `elif Answer >= '21'` , but hit the nail on the head with the first one :-)

Comment: Thanks for helping, however, I tried what you said (to the best my pea-brain can comprehend), but now it says I have an error with "print" Sorry if i'm a bit of a nuisance here. `Answer = input("Yo stupid, What\'s nine plus ten?")
if Answer == '19' print("Your smarter then me.")
elif Answer >= '21' print("You stupid!")`

Comment: Don't forget to use the colons at the end of each `if`/`elif`

Answer (score 0):

`else:` does not take a condition afterwards. In your case use `elif <condition>:`.